# How to block Windows XP and IE6 users from my site? :P

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I'd like to redirect away from my site any user who use windows xp with IE6 and IE7.

Can you help me? ;)

Thx

Comment: so.... what have you tried?

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: Take a look at the Javascript `navigator` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted your attempt, I'll give you steps to help you along the way.

PHP has built in function you can use to achieve this.

---

Have a look at [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function.

Example output:

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```